# how to pick or select or use mobile date picker

Tags: html, css, mobile

I am accessing my site in mobile, there is a field called enter date & enter time,

When i click that date field i want to show my mobile date picker,

How to implement ?

am view site in my sony ericsson k530i

Comment: Can you please be more specific about the code you want help with? We need to know specifically what script you're using and the code you need help with otherwise it's like the blind leading the blind.

Comment: Check this site in mobile http://happylife.in/mobile/view/expenditure/expense.php there is a text field Date, when i click date field i want to select my default date mobile date pick

Comment: What is the specific date picker code? Are you using jQuery Mobile or another code set? For example there are some solutions that use the id value in an input field to determine if the date picker should be run.

Comment: i should call default mobile date picker

Comment: I have done a fair bit of searching on this and can't really find much useful information for you, my suggestion would be to look at a mobile framework like jQuery Mobile and use that. Sorry I can't help much more than that

Comment: thx for research, my mobile does not suppoer Javascript, so looking compatible for mobile(Sony Ericson k530)

Comment: I found docs that says that it does support JS... maybe double check this fact, maybe there is a better mobile browser for you to use like Opera. Good luck mate

Answer (score 0):

HTML has new input types that trigger the specialized interfaces on mobile.  If you switch to an HTML5 doctype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

and use the following:

```
<input type="date" >
```

you should get the interface you're looking for.  It will degrade to a simple text input on browsers that don't support HTML5.

Comment: http://www.happylife.in/mobile/source/mobile.php check this link in mobile, here i used the input type date , but in mobile it is working as normal text box, please check and update

Comment: i am using sony Erickson k530i

Comment: My apologies.  I thought I had seen this work, but it turns out that Opera is the only browser natively supporting a date picker at this point.  At some point, I expect this to work.

Comment: for me in opera also its not working, even i saw in some blogs they also saying this, but for me it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use `<input type="date" />` as stated above.
However there are browsers that don't support those HTML5 elements.

Check out [mobiscroll date picker](http://demo.mobiscroll.com/). You can use it with jQuery or ZeptoJS.